# How to make a share button via apps in as 3

Tags: button, share, actionscript-3

I am making an Android app and I want to make a share button, similar to the buttons found in Google play, so I can add text and photos. See the button surrounded by the red circle in:

[image: this image]

Comment: i mean so i can share text or photos

Comment: Where are you **sharing** to? Most sites like Twitter or Facebook have tutorials online about how to share to their pages. Did you try searching for any tutorials? Ask here when stuck and can **show some AS3 code** of what you tried. Someone can help you fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [ShareActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html)

[Adding an Easy Share Action](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 (AIR) i dont think theres a built in API for that yet. But your in luck, here is a paid ANE already built for you. You might be able to find a cheap or free one if you search around i dont know. https://www.milkmanplugins.com/goviral-facebook-and-sharing-air-ane